# IE11 Object 'indexOf' property error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, webpack-dev-server

I am using react with Webpack using babel loader. I am creating an app.bundle.js and is working fine in Chrome. However I am not able to run in IE 11 as it gives me the following error "Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'  in `app.bundle.js` while loading index.html.
I have included the `babel-polyfill` in webpack entry also  `entry : ['babel-polyfill' , './src/index.js'],`
Also I tried including `babel-polyfill` using `import` statement in `index.js` too but no luck. Also tried including in core-js using `import` in `index.js` but not able to resolve.

Comment: Have you imported the `babel-polyfill` in your code? `import "babel-polyfill";`

Comment: yes I tried importing that too but no luck

Comment: Ah, I see. Your browser seems to think it is < IE9. Do you have a doctype at the top of your HTML? `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for guiding. Doctype was already there but adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  this resolved the issue. Looks very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your browser is in an IE8 environment. Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your HTML file and the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` meta tag.